# NVIDIA Apex Integration with kaggle

Tags: nvidia, kaggle

I am trying to integrate nvidia apex with my kaggle notebook,but i keep on running into error.

code used:

## !git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex

## %cd apex

## !pip install -v --no-cache-dir --global-option="--cpp_ext" --global-option="--cuda_ext" --global-option="--deprecated_fused_adam" --global-option="--xentropy" --global-option="--fast_multihead_attn" .

can someone help me with this?

Running this give error message.
Using pip 23.3.2 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
DEPRECATION: --build-option and --global-option are deprecated. pip 24.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use --config-settings. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11859 class="ansi-yellow-fg">
WARNING: Implying --no-binary=:all: due to the presence of --build-option / --global-option.
Processing /kaggle/working/apex
Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
Collecting setuptools
Downloading setuptools-69.1.1.tar.gz (2.2 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0.0/2.2 MB ? eta -:--:--
━━━╸━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0.2/2.2 MB 6.1 MB/s eta 0:00:01
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╸━━━━━━━━━━ 1.6/2.2 MB 23.9 MB/s eta 0:00:01
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.2/2.2 MB 23.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Getting requirements to build wheel: started
Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
Installing backend dependencies: started
Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting wheel
Using cached wheel-0.42.0-py3-none-any.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: setuptools
Building wheel for setuptools (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for setuptools (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for setuptools: filename=setuptools-69.1.1-py3-none-any.whl size=819326 sha256=6ae1d142afaf98db3d10ef0cc75dce10cc0927452bf106895a0ffd9671abba7b
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/0a/90/6c/3dbffbb35c4c80426620b1fcb7ee37b0c09754b9670ec4ea1c
Successfully built setuptools
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow-decision-forests 1.8.1 requires wurlitzer, which is not installed.
libpysal 4.9.2 requires packaging>=22, but you have packaging 21.3 which is incompatible.
libpysal 4.9.2 requires shapely>=2.0.1, but you have shapely 1.8.5.post1 which is incompatible.
momepy 0.7.0 requires shapely>=2, but you have shapely 1.8.5.post1 which is incompatible.
osmnx 1.9.1 requires shapely>=2.0, but you have shapely 1.8.5.post1 which is incompatible.
spopt 0.6.0 requires shapely>=2.0.1, but you have shapely 1.8.5.post1 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.15.0 requires keras<2.16,>=2.15.0, but you have keras 3.0.5 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed setuptools-69.1.1 wheel-0.42.0
Installing build dependencies ... done
Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in 
main()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kuweadsy/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kuweadsy/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "/tmp/pip-build-env-kuweadsy/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 5, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
full command: /opt/conda/bin/python3.10 /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmpnpid1ff6
cwd: /kaggle/working/apex
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
add Codeadd Markdown

Comment: Hello! Thank you for reaching out on StackOverflow. However, it seems like your question might need some clarification and formatting adjustments to help the community better understand and assist you. Could you please provide more details about what specific issue you're facing or what you're trying to achieve? Additionally, organizing your question with proper formatting and clear language can greatly improve its readability and the likelihood of receiving helpful responses. Don't hesitate to [edit] your question to make it clearer and more accessible for everyone.